# Why is Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] different from Request.Url.Host?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Same server, same site - two different results.

## Case 1

request URL: domain.com (resolving to domain.com/default.aspx)
request header in Firebug: domain.com
`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` = domain.com
`Request.Url.Host` = domain.com (Ok, this is good and expected)

## Case 2

request URL: domain.com/default.aspx
request header in Firebug: domain.com
`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]` = domain.com
`Request.Url.Host` = **app5** (name of the server)

Looking at two requests I can't see anything that would cause that. Why would this be the case?
Server is running Windows 2003 and IIS6.

Comment: Does this happen on other sites on your server?  I can't recreate it on my IIS 7 / 2008 box.

Comment: @Josh This is the only regular ASP.NET site we have on that server. I will try to create a new blank site on Monday (don't have access to that colo from home).

Answer (score 2):

you should check whether the IIS metabase is setup to use the hostname or a different name

command -> `cscript adsutil.vbs get W3SVC/SITE-ID/USEHOSTNAME`

Result  -> should be

`The parameter "USEHOSTNAME" is not set at this node.`

or 
`USEHOSTNAME                     : (BOOLEAN) False`

command -> `cscript adsutil.vbs get W3SVC/SITE-ID/SETHOSTNAME`

Result  -> should be

`The parameter "SETHOSTNAME" is not set at this node.`

or `SETHOSTNAME                     : (STRING) ""`

change SITE-ID with the numeric id of the site.

If you see any other result that means somebody has modified the above two properties of the site.

Comment: oh wow, this was a while ago... I don't even work for that company any more, but thanks for trying :)